# Updating a restaurant logo

Tags: logo, critique, font-recommendation, branding

"Kitchen 154" is a "punkish" restaurant that offers casual spicy food in Madrid, Spain, and I am updating their logo.

They started with a lean DIN 1451 Std font. Now I am "grunging" it a little bit.

1. Is it too obvious to use grungy artline with the concept "casual-rock and roll cooking"? I prefer to use full-filled shapes with one color instead of textures. This logo will have to work for printing, signs and online.
2. Is the pepper too "mellow and nice"? Do I need to use a different style of pepper? Peppers and hot food is very obvious IMHO (along with flames and fire) but clients really love it... Any suggestions to replace the pepper?
3. Same with red-black colors. What other colors would work as well?
4. "NI GASTRO NI POLLAS" is quite rude as a claim, and people love it. It means something like "Food. No snooty shit here".

Am I on the right direction? Are the new logos better than the old ones?

[image: Logo Evolution]

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design! You started asking about the font and then went on about colors and everything else. It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: I also edited your question to make it more clear, but regardless you should [edit] to make it more focused in a single problem for which you want an answer.

Comment: I upvoted your question because since a long time we haven't seen a well-formulated criticism question about a logo design.

Comment: So you settled with this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJ5gf.png

Answer (score 0):

I would make it more cleaner, without this "strip" effect and without the double text. I like, especially the last version but i would make it "flat".

Answer (score 0):

I second Gianmarco's answer in making the logo cleaner (and liking the last version). The double text does not make it any more edgy, but it does make it less readable and less appealing (my opinion).

If you want to make the text more interesting, I would suggest using similar effects as you use on the pepper and outline. You can ruff it up a bit with similar "smudges" or just break up the font's clean edges.

As I don't speak spanish, I cannot really evaluate the tag line, but if it's considered good, I see no reason why not to incorporate it into the last two versions as well.

Finally, I don't think that "obvious" is necessarily bad. When looking for a restaurant, or any service, really, knowing what to expect from their signage is a big plus.

Answer (score 0):

I think your thought process for the logo is very sound. I am personally drawn to the first works in progress logo (with the Ni Gastro Ni Pollas slogan), and would like to see that logo without the red lines.

The more compact 2014/2015 logos add an impressive tension and bold aesthetic that is a lot more nuanced and interesting than the highly texturized "grungy" look that you mentioned. I think messing with the spacing of the logo text and icons could help achieve that bold, edgy look instead of heading down the textured route.

I'm curious if the title of the kitchen is ever abbreviated to "154" in conversation. Increasing the "154" in contrast to the kitchen again provides more of an identity to the kitchen, which again leads me to be more drawn to the confidence visualized in the 2014 logo.

I overall agree with your preference to steer away from the textured grunginess, and I think the peppers look more spicy and enticing without the texture overlay. Tweaking the spacing and sizing of the icons and text could create the emphasis needed without needing to break up the logo with the grunge.

Best of luck!